# UITextChecker with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to make use of Apple's UITextChecker in Xcode 8 to automatically search for spelling errors in a string of words and give suggestions as to replacements. I'm relatively new to referencing Apple API's so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So what have you tried? Your question is very broad and not about a specific problem. Or do you just expect us to write it for you? [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use it:

```
func correctWord(word: String, language: String = "en") -> Bool {
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: word.utf16.count)
    let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: language)

    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
}
```

Note that the language parameter is optional, but you could pass it if you would like to change language from `"en"`.

Call it:

```
let x = correctWord(word: "yweyuw") // false
let y = correctWord(word: "Hello") // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method: "rangeOfMisspelledWordInString"

For overview you can read documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextchecker?language=objc

```
let word = "Testar"
let textChecker = UITextChecker()
let misspelledRange = textChecker.rangeOfMisspelledWordInString(
            word, range: NSRange(0..<word.utf16.count), startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_US")

        if misspelledRange.location != NSNotFound,
            let guesses = textChecker.guessesForWordRange(
                misspelledRange, inString: word, language: "en_US") as? [String]
        {
            print("Guess: \(guesses.first)") //Output is: Guess: Optional("Tester")

        } else {
            print("Not found")
        }
```